# I am trying to write a function F_CHECK_STRING ,It checks if the complete word is found within the text

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, stored-functions

Write a function F_CHECK_STRING which takes 2 input parameters:

- P_TEXT of type character
- P_WORD of type character

It checks if the complete word is found within the text return 1 otherwise return 0. The search must be case insensitive.

i.e.: the text is a set of words delimited by spaces.

Example:

- Text is “In English Hello Word” and the word is “hello”, in this case return 1
- Text is “In English Hello word” and the word is “he”, in this case return 0

---

```
 create or replace function F_CHECK_STRING (P_TEXT  in CHARACTER, 
                                            P_WORD  in CHARACTER,
                                            P_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR2) 
 return NUMBER
 IS
 begin
  IF P_TEXT:= SUBSTR(LOWER('In English Hello Word'),12,5) LIKE LOWER ('hello');
  THEN
     RETURN 1;
  ELSE
     P_TEXT := SUBSTR(LOWER('In English Hello Word'),12,5) LIKE LOWER ('he');
  THEN
     RETURN 0;
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       P_MESSAGE := 'FAILED To Return ' || P_TEXT || '- SQL ERROR: '||SQLERRM;
end F_CHECK_STRING ;
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question, you have multiple possibilities, hope that this can help

## CODE

1. Using the like operator

```
create or replace function F_CHECK_STRING (P_TEXT  in VARCHAR2, 
                                            P_WORD  in VARCHAR2) 
return NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  IF (LOWER(P_TEXT) LIKE '% ' || LOWER(P_WORD) || ' %' ) THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSIF (LOWER(P_TEXT) LIKE LOWER(P_WORD) || ' %' ) THEN
    -- Matches the beginning of a string
    RETURN 1;
  ELSIF (LOWER(P_TEXT) LIKE '% ' || LOWER(P_WORD) || '' ) THEN
    -- Matches the end of a string
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

2. using the substr operator, please see the previous answer
3. use regexp_like operator (my recommendation)

```
create or replace function F_CHECK_STRING (P_TEXT  in VARCHAR2, 
                                            P_WORD  in VARCHAR2) 
return NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  -- \s means a whitespace character
  -- ^  Matches the beginning of a string.In multiline mode, it matches the beginning of any line anywhere within the source string.
  -- $  Matches the end of a string. In multiline mode, it matches the end of any line anywhere within the source string.
  -- 'i' specifies case-insensitive matching
  -- more https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html
  IF regexp_like (P_TEXT, '(^|\s)' || P_WORD || '(\s|$)', 'i') THEN
     RETURN 1;
  ELSE
     RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

## TEST

```
select F_CHECK_STRING ('In English Hello Word', 'hello') as "hello", 
       F_CHECK_STRING ('In English Hello Word', 'IN') as "IN",
       F_CHECK_STRING ('In English Hello Word', 'he') as "he",
       F_CHECK_STRING ('In English Hello Word', 'WORD') as "WORD"
from dual;

HELLO IN HE WORD 
----- -- -- ---- 
    1  1  0    1
```

## TIP

You can use regexp_like in sql queries, no need to create a custom function

```
select 1 FROM DUAL
where regexp_like ('In English Hello Word', '(^|\s)' || 'hello' || '(\s|$)', 'i') 
;

select 1 FROM DUAL
where regexp_like ('In English Hello Word', '(^|\s)' || 'he' || '(\s|$)', 'i') 
;

SELECT CASE WHEN regexp_like ('In English Hello Word', '(^|\s)' || 'hello' || '(\s|$)', 'i')
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
from dual;

SELECT CASE WHEN regexp_like ('In English Hello Word', '(^|\s)' || 'he' || '(\s|$)', 'i')
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do? See comments within code.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_check_string
  2    (p_text in varchar2, p_word in varchar2)
  3  return number
  4  is
  5    l_len    number := length(p_word);
  6    l_pos    number;          -- position of P_WORD in P_TEXT
  7    l_char_a varchar2(1);     -- character in front of P_WORD
  8    l_char_b varchar2(1);     -- character behind P_WORD
  9    retval   number(1) := 0;  -- return value
 10  begin
 11    l_pos := instr(lower(p_text), lower(p_word));
 12
 13    if l_pos > 0 then
 14       -- word exists in text; see if it is complete
 15       l_char_a := case when l_pos = 1 then ' '
 16                        else substr(p_text, l_pos - 1, 1)
 17                   end;
 18       l_char_b := case when l_pos = 1 then ' '
 19                        else nvl(substr(p_text, l_pos + l_len, 1), ' ')
 20                   end;
 21
 22       -- everything is OK if both L_CHARs are empty strings
 23       if l_char_a = ' ' and
 24          l_char_b = ' '
 25       then
 26          retval := 1;
 27       end if;
 28    end if;
 29    return retval;
 30  end;
 31  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select
  2    f_check_string('In English Hello Word', 'hello') res1,
  3    f_check_string('In English Hello Word', 'he'   ) res2,
  4    f_check_string('In English Hello Word', 'in'   ) res3,
  5    f_check_string('In English Hello Word', 'word' ) res4,
  6    f_check_string('In English Hello Word', 'ord'  ) res5
  7  from dual;

      RES1       RES2       RES3       RES4       RES5
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0          1          1          0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering alphanumeric characters as individual words, the `[[:alnum:]]` POSIX might be used to split the text into word pieces as splitting by *space*, *punctuation* and *special characters*, *all those are considered to be in the exception list* for a word here, as in the following code block :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_Check_String ( i_text VARCHAR2, i_word VARCHAR2 ) 
RETURN INT IS
   o_result  INT;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*)
     INTO o_result
     FROM ( SELECT i_text FROM dual )
    WHERE LOWER(i_word) = REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(i_text),'[[:alnum:]]+',1,level)
  CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(i_text,'[[:alnum:]]+');

   RETURN o_result;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=92c46585e4453a69a4fea44cb9de9188)</kbd>

*P.S: The function won't hurl with any exception message through use of `COUNT` aggregation as in the current case. So, p_message OUT parameter is not needed*

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE` for this. '\W' stands for non-word character. '^' is the string start and '$' is the string end.

```
select 
  case when regexp_like (:p_text, '(^|\W)' || :p_word || '(\W|$)', 'i')
    then 1
    else 0
  end as match
from dual;
```

You can of course wrap this in a function:

```
create or replace function f_check_string
(
  p_text  in varchar2, 
  p_word  in varchar2
) return number is
begin
  if regexp_like (p_text, '(^|\W)' || p_word || '(\W|$)', 'i') then 
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
  end if;
end f_check_string;
```